# Difference between おじいさん and おじさん

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent

I'm wondering if there is much difference in the pronunciation of the words or intonation of them. Is it just the long vowel?

Answer (score 8):

- おじいさん with the long //iː// sound means "grandfather".
- おじさん with the short //i// sound means "uncle".

In modern Japanese, these are distinguished by vowel length and by pitch accent -- "grandfather" has a downstep after the second mora, so the *ji* is a higher pitch than the second *i*: おじいさん{LHLLL}, whereas "uncle" has no downstep: おじさん{LHHH}.

Looking at the derivations, the initial *o-* in "grandfather" is an honorific prefix, and the *-san* on the end is an honorific suffix.  The root term is *jī*, from older *jiji* (still encountered occasionally, often meaning "old man"), from ancient *didi*.

Meanwhile, in "uncle", the *-san* on the end is an honorific suffix, but the *o-* on the front is part of the root term, *oji*.  This is from older *woji*, from ancient *wodi*.

Comment: I can't figure out how to format for the pitch accent, with the red lines above or below the kana.  If anyone could add that to this post, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Does that look alright?

Comment: @user27280: Tweaked and expanded.  **Thank you!**

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi see https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se for details on the special markdown additions for the Japanese SE site. (there's also a link to that page at the top of the markdown editing "advanced help" page)

Comment: @Foogod, thanks, but already solved over a year ago.  :)  Cheers!